# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

im getting the following error log:

```
05-29 20:57:29.886: D/AndroidRuntime(359): Shutting down VM
05-29 20:57:29.896: W/dalvikvm(359): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
05-29 20:57:29.896: E/AndroidRuntime(359): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-29 20:57:29.906: E/AndroidRuntime(359): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dd.qsg/com.dd.qsg.QSGActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 20:57:29.906: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
05-29 20:57:29.906: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
05-29 20:57:29.906: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
05-29 20:57:29.906: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
05-29 20:57:29.906: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-29 20:57:29.906: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-29 20:57:29.906: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-29 20:57:29.906: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 20:57:29.906: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-29 20:57:29.906: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-29 20:57:29.906: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-29 20:57:29.906: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-29 20:57:29.906: E/AndroidRuntime(359): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 20:57:29.906: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at com.dd.qsg.DatabaseHandler.getLongestSmoke(DatabaseHandler.java:85)
05-29 20:57:29.906: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at com.dd.qsg.QSGActivity.onCreate(QSGActivity.java:40)
05-29 20:57:29.906: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-29 20:57:29.906: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
05-29 20:57:29.906: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  ... 11 more
05-29 20:57:29.926: I/dalvikvm(359): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
05-29 20:57:29.926: E/dalvikvm(359): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
05-29 20:57:31.206: I/Process(359): Sending signal. PID: 359 SIG: 9
```

i dont know how to fix this. where is it telling me i need to fix something?

heres line 85 of DatabaseHandler.java:

```
theCount = context.getResources().getString(R.string.na);
```

heres the whole function:

```
public String getLongestSmoke(Context context) {
    String theCount = "";  
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT millis FROM records ORDER BY CAST(millis as SIGNED) DESC", null);

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();    
        theCount = cursor.getString(0);
    }
    else {
        theCount = context.getResources().getString(R.string.na);
    }

    cursor.close();        
    return humanTime(theCount);
}
```

heres the line in the onCreate method of the main activity that uses this function:

```
    longestGone.setText(getString(R.string.longest_gone) + " " +  db.getLongestSmoke(null));
```

it was working fine before when it was null and now stopped all of the sudden. what am i supposed to make it?

this was working fine until i made the following changes to the onCreate of my DatabaseHandler class:

```
    String CREATE_ACHIEVEMENTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE achievements ("
             + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
             + "name VARCHAR,"
             + "type VARCHAR,"
             + "value VARCHAR,"
             + "completed VARCHAR"
             + ")";              

    db.execSQL(CREATE_ACHIEVEMENTS_TABLE);      

    db.execSQL("insert into achievements (name, type, value, completed) values ('30 minutes', 'time', '1800000', 'no')");
    db.execSQL("insert into achievements (name, type, value, completed) values ('1 hour', 'time', '3600000', 'no')");
    db.execSQL("insert into achievements (name, type, value, completed) values ('2 hours', 'time', '7200000', 'no')");
    db.execSQL("insert into achievements (name, type, value, completed) values ('6 hours', 'time', '21600000', 'no')");
    db.execSQL("insert into achievements (name, type, value, completed) values ('12 hours', 'time', '43200000', 'no')");
    db.execSQL("insert into achievements (name, type, value, completed) values ('1 day', 'time', '86400000', 'no')");
    db.execSQL("insert into achievements (name, type, value, completed) values ('2 days', 'time', '172800000', 'no')");
    db.execSQL("insert into achievements (name, type, value, completed) values ('1 week', 'time', '604800000', 'no')");
    db.execSQL("insert into achievements (name, type, value, completed) values ('2 weeks', 'time', '1209600000', 'no')");
    db.execSQL("insert into achievements (name, type, value, completed) values ('1 month', 'time', '2592000000', 'no')");
    db.execSQL("insert into achievements (name, type, value, completed) values ('2 months', 'time', '5184000000', 'no')");
    db.execSQL("insert into achievements (name, type, value, completed) values ('6 months', 'time', '15552000000', 'no')");
    db.execSQL("insert into achievements (name, type, value, completed) values ('1 year', 'time', '31536000000', 'no')");
    db.execSQL("insert into achievements (name, type, value, completed) values ('Set a record', 'milestone', '', 'no')");
    db.execSQL("insert into achievements (name, type, value, completed) values ('Beat top record', 'milestone', '', 'no')");
```

i also added this to the onUpgrade:

```
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS achievements");
```

Comment: post some code (especially the line related with NullPointerException)

Comment: com.dd.qsg.DatabaseHandler:85, to be precise :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
05-29 20:57:29.906: E/AndroidRuntime(359): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 20:57:29.906: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at com.dd.qsg.DatabaseHandler.getLongestSmoke(DatabaseHandler.java:85)
```

There's your clue. Something on line 85 of DatabaseHandler.java is trying to dereference a null reference.

In the light of your edit, I'd guess that `context` is null, then.

And in the light of your **second** edit:

```
db.getLongestSmoke(null)
```

You are passing in `null` as the `context` parameter. Pass in a valid `Context` instead. Try:

```
db.getLongestSmoke(this)
```

where `this` is the Activity whose `onCreate` this call is coming from.

Comment: I'd guess that context is null, then.

Comment: it was working fine before though, i dont get it. check my OP 1 more time to see what changes i made before this error started happening...

Comment: You are passing in a null context, and then trying to dereference it. That is the problem. Whatever else you think you changed is irrelevant.

Comment: im dumb. youre right. i put "this" as the context and its working now. thank you graham.

Comment: @scarhand, your code doesn't use `context` if `cursor.getCount() > 0`, so it's possible that there were rows in the `records` table before, which would have hidden the error.

Comment: you are absolutely right david, i realized this because i had re-installed the app

Answer (score 4):

Here:

```
05-29 20:57:29.906: E/AndroidRuntime(359): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 20:57:29.906: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at com.dd.qsg.DatabaseHandler.getLongestSmoke(DatabaseHandler.java:85)
```

I tells you that on line 85 of file DatabaseHelper.java you have a null value that you can't access.

EDIT:

According to your edited post it's the line:

`theCount = context.getResources().getString(R.string.na);`

`context` is null and causes NPE.

Comment: I mean, you asked "where is it telling you", that's the answer. I can help you better if you provide the code and specify the 85th line

Comment: Not to be rude or anything, but this proves that the rep system is broken.

Comment: I agree. I posted some really nice posts solving some real problems and got mere 4 upvotes and here I get nearly the same amount for something that simple...

Comment: michal, i edited the OP once again, and i dont know why it just stopped working all of the sudden. the changes i made were to the onCreate method of the DatabaseHandler, i simply made it add a new database table and insert rows into it....

Comment: Well you put null there, so the NPE is legit. `longestGone.setText(getString(R.string.longest_gone) + " " +  db.getLongestSmoke(null));` - replace null by `this` (if it's in an activity)

Answer (score -3):

It looks like DatabaseHandler is null

Comment: You can't possibly know what is null without seeing the code.

Comment: and as the NPE is thrown in a method of DatabaseHandler one can at least say that the DatabaseHanlder is not null!

Comment: Please don't post single-line answers. Explain the issue. -1